# Screwed up system by installing both open jdk 8 and open jdk 9

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

The command:

```
file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
```

gives me the output

```
/etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/etc/alternatives/javac: symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

So basically I am using both Java 8 and Java 9 at the same time, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting proper versions by running these commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```